# How to make array_walk_recursive visit every node?

Tags: php, recursion

I have a recursive `$data` structure that I need to modify. Each node considered an `$item` should get a property with the value of `$value` added. Things that I tried (and how they failed) are:

- `array_walk_recursive`: Visits only leaf nodes.
- Stack/queue: I failed to modify the original structure but only altered the copies on the stack/queue.
- Loops: Without the stack/queue approach I would need to know the nesting level and write an awful lot of nested loops.
- `array_map`: I failed to write a proper recursive callback given that the value of `$value` is not static but the result of previous code. So it must somehow get "into" the callback. Since `use` is only available to anonymous functions I did not manage to write a recursive one.
- Loop and recursive function: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29161370/948404) to a similar question failed for the same reason as the `array_map` approach.

My situation in code looks similar to this example:

```
<?php

$value = 'example';

$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar'
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'items' => array(
                array('foo' => 'bar')
            )
        )
    )
);

// do this recursively to every member of an 'items' property:
$item['baz'] = $value;
```

Can you think of a different approach or help me straighten out one of those that I failed at so far?

**Update**

Some code that I tried that did not work:

```
// Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{'

function do (&$item) use ($value) {

    $item['baz'] = $value;

    foreach ($item['items'] as $next) {

        do($next);
    }
}

// Undefined variable: value

function do (&$item) {

    $item['baz'] = $value;

    foreach ($item['items'] as $next) {

        do($next);
    }
}

foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {

    do($item);
}
```

Works for now (I would prefer not having to pass the `$value` parameter, though):

```
function do (&$item, $value) {

    $item['baz'] = $value;

    foreach ($item['items'] as &$next) {

        do($next, $value);
    }
}

foreach ($data['items'] as &$item) {

    do($item, $value);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a *recursive function*...?

Comment: `I would need to know the nesting level and write an awful lot of nested loops.` ough? You seem to missed thing called recursion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: The approach that you are citing was to explicitly avoid recursion.

Comment: I am saying that your problem can be easily solved with recursion. You also showed no code you made so far which may be quite crucial for the problems you are facing.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, as noted in approaches 4 and 5.

Comment: You can use array traverse from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003062/return-all-keys-of-nested-array/

Answer (score 0):

Check this code for get each key and value:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$value = 'example';

$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'items' => array( array( 'foo' => 'bar','items' => array(array('foo' => 'bar') ) ) )
);


$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
  foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {
        echo $k.'=>'.$v;
        echo '</br>';
  }

?>
```

Formatting was necessary but did not suffice for the minimum edit length. So I added this otherwise useless text.

Comment: This one doesn't visit top level keys if they have a sub array.

Answer (score 0):

The following recursive function works for me. Note that it requires to pass parameters by reference also inside the `foreach` loop:

```
$value = 'example';

function do (&$item, $value) {

    $item['baz'] = $value;

    foreach ($item['items'] as &$next) {

        do($next, $value);
    }
}

foreach ($data['items'] as &$item) {

    do($item, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param array $arr
 * @param callable $callback
 * @param array $options
 *
 *
 * Example:
 * (this will add the link property to every node in the array recursively)
 *
 *
 * $linkFmt = "/mylink/{type}/{slug}";
 * ArrayTool::updateNodeRecursive($ret, function (array &$row) use ($linkFmt) {
 *      $row['link'] = str_replace([
 *          "{type}",
 *          "{slug}",
 *      ], [
 *          $row['type'],
 *          $row['slug'],
 *          ], $linkFmt);
 * });
 *
 *
 *
 *
 */
public static function updateNodeRecursive(array &$arr, callable $callback, array $options = [])
{
    $childrenKey = $options['childrenKey'] ?? "children";
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        call_user_func_array($callback, [&$v]);

        if (array_key_exists($childrenKey, $v) && $v[$childrenKey]) {
            $children = $v[$childrenKey];
            self::updateNodeRecursive($children, $callback, $options);
            $v[$childrenKey] = $children;
        }
        $arr[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```